# How add a second node to my cluster?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I am trying to solve a problem that I have with elasticsearch and magento 2.3, and I have been recommended to add a new node but I do not know how to launch the query from the terminal, can someone help me? I have elasticsearc on the same server where I have Magento (ubuntu + nginx)